# Limit numbers of result on a polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have a User model that defines the following relationship

```
public function labelsWatchlist()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Label', 'object', 'users_watchlists')->where('users_watchlists.object_type', '=', 'Label');
}
```

This works well, and I can easily retrieve all rows through

```
$user->labelsWatchlist
```

How could pagination be implemented in that case ? Say I would like to retrieve only 5 items from the $user->labelsWatchlist call, is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I just came to that problem and figured the solution. 
It might be too late for you but this is the solution.

```
  public function labelsWatchlist($limit = 5)
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Label', 'object', 'users_watchlists')->where('users_watchlists.object_type', '=', 'Label')->limit($limit);
}
```

this is how to get how many results you would like

```
$user->labelsWatchlist(10)->get()
```

Anyway I hope it helps someone......